# redirect all request to index.html

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I'm trying to redirect all unknown requests to index.html. For example if someone enters:

```
http://IP_Address/blah_blah _blah
```

Then it must redirect to index.html. Below is the code I have tried:

I have my root dir under `/var/www/some_dir/index.html`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule . index.html [R=302,L]
```

When I tried this code, it's redirecting to `http://Ip_address/var/www/accesspage/index.html`

I want `http://Ip_address/index.html`

But I want to redirect to other html pages via index.html

Below is my Apache config

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/access/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/access/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have your webserver configuration screwy.

Comment: I have added apache congi check it out , its all correect

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule . /index.html [R=302,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use .htaccess to make a custom 404 page and on that page use header() to redirect the user.
(If you don't want to use php you can redirect with javascript too)

Comment: Make a page names 404.html, and in your htaccess file write:
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html. Then 
in the 404.html page redirect the user using javascript